# Absolute positioned element outside of overflow hidden div

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I have a problem that overflow hidden is clipping away the text of an absolute positioned element..

Here is the example:

```
<div style="display: flex; overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="swiper-container" style="flex: 1; overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="wrapper" style="position: relative;">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div style="position: absolute; margin-top: -10px; ">text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

.swiper-slide element is taken from a php loop since I am using a swipe carousel. Also all parent overflow:hidden elements are hiding previous/next carousels so we can't play that much with changing the structure.

Also Jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/egh5oz9h/

I would like "text" to be displayed above the grey box.. So outside of the parent elements with overflow hidden..

Comment: make this `<div style="position: absolute; margin-top: -10px; ">text</div>` look like this `<div style="position: absolute;">text</div>` -  that will stop the text being clipped off. or add inside padding to push the text back down

Comment: You cannot overcome this. That's how the `overflow: hidden` is intended to work. [Read more here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/#article-header-id-2).

Comment: why margin-top:-10px  ??

Comment: it's unclear exactly what you want to happen. the negative margin and overflow hidden combination are working as they should... how should it change to be what you want?

Comment: I would like "text" to be displayed above the grey box.. So outside of the parent elements with overflow hidden..

Comment: Yes but that's like saying, I want the color to be blue... but it needs to be green

Comment: `<div style="display: flex; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="flex: 1 1 0%; overflow: hidden;" class="swiper-container">
  
        <div class="wrapper" style="position: absolute;">
        <div style="position: absolute;">text</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
        
        </div>
        
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>`

Comment: @120382833  use above code and check

Comment: @Anant thanks for trying, but the text div block has to be inside the swiper-slide, since it's a php loop and the text needs to change when swiping left/right

Comment: @chirag I am trying to move the text outside of the box.. overflow hidden is hiding other swiper-slide elements left/right of it, since it's a php loop and you're moving between them, seeing only 1 at a time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change position absolute to position fixed.

HTML

```
<div style="display: flex; overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="swiper-container" style="flex: 1; overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="wrapper" style="position: relative;">

      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div style="position: fixed; margin-top: -10px;">text</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.swiper-slide {
  background: #999;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/frankspin/pen/kXVNdK)

Comment: Works.. Thank you very much!!